# Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xbbf

Tags: anchor, rust, instructions, error

I get the following error when trying to execute an instruction:
Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xbbf

This is the account:

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateRaffle<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"raffle".as_ref(), entrants.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = creator,
        space = 8 + 300, // Option serialization workaround
    )]
    pub raffle: Account<'info, Raffle>,
    #[account(zero)]
    pub entrants: AccountLoader<'info, Entrants>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub creator: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [raffle.key().as_ref(), b"proceeds"],
        bump,
        payer = creator,
        token::mint = proceeds_mint,
        token::authority = raffle,
    )]
    pub proceeds: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub proceeds_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    /// CHECK:
    #[account(mut, address = Pubkey::from_str(FEE_WALLET).unwrap())]
    pub fee_acc: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}
```

This is the function which tries to execute the instruction:

```
fn create_raffle(
    program_id: Pubkey,
    program_client: &anchor_client::Program,
    proceeds_mint: Pubkey,
    ticket_price: u64,
    end_date_utc: String,
    entrants_keypair: Option<String>,
    max_entrants: Option<u32>,
    // fee_acc: Pubkey,
) -> Result<()> {
    let entrants_keypair = match entrants_keypair {
        Some(entrants_keypair) => {
            read_keypair_file(entrants_keypair).expect("Could not find entrants keypair")
        }
        _ => Keypair::new(),
    };

    let (raffle, _) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[b"raffle".as_ref(), entrants_keypair.pubkey().as_ref()],
        &program_id,
    );
    let (proceeds, _) =
        Pubkey::find_program_address(&[raffle.as_ref(), b"proceeds".as_ref()], &program_id);

    // Request arguments
    let clock = deserialize::<Clock>(
        &program_client
            .rpc()
            .get_account(&sysvar::clock::ID)
            .unwrap()
            .data,
    )
    .unwrap();
    let date_time = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(&end_date_utc, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")?;
    let end_timestamp: i64 = date_time.timestamp();

    let entrants_account_size = 8 + size_of::<draffle::Entrants>();
    program_client
        .request()
        .instruction(system_instruction::create_account(
            &program_client.payer(),
            &entrants_keypair.pubkey(),
            program_client
                .rpc()
                .get_minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption(entrants_account_size)?,
            entrants_account_size as u64,
            &program_id,
        ))
        .accounts(draffle::accounts::CreateRaffle {
            raffle,
            entrants: entrants_keypair.pubkey(),
            creator: program_client.payer(),
            proceeds,
            proceeds_mint,
            fee_acc: Pubkey::from_str(FEE_WALLET).unwrap(),
            system_program: system_program::id(),
            token_program: spl_token::id(),
            rent: sysvar::rent::ID,
        })
        .args(draffle::instruction::CreateRaffle {
            end_timestamp,
            ticket_price,
            max_entrants: max_entrants.unwrap_or(draffle::ENTRANTS_SIZE),
        })
        .signer(&entrants_keypair)
        .send()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

These are the arguments im trying to run the program with:

```
target/debug/draffle create-raffle \
    EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v \ # SPL token mint address that can be used to buy tickets, this is USDC
    1 \ # Cost per ticket in given token
    "2023-05-22 14:55" \ # Raffle end date in UTC timezone. Double check this if you encounter a 0x1771 error.
    --max-entrants 420 \ # Max tickets available for given raffle
    --provider.cluster devnet \ # Cluster
    --provider.wallet operations/keypair.json # Keypair to execute command with
    --program-id rafqXZRn7bbyoNQ8Eua1JMkKYZ7HmQmiwSyEgf8E1Di # Deployed raffle program
```

This is the program deployed:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/rafqXZRn7bbyoNQ8Eua1JMkKYZ7HmQmiwSyEgf8E1Di?cluster=devnet

If anymore details are needed, this is the repo im trying to make work:
https://github.com/reecen96/Riff-Raffle-Solana-NFT